When i try to start my automation project from jenkins i got an error. org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session
There is full error message: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /home/nodeuser/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/124.0.6367.207/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
I used:
java 17,
maven 3.9.6
selenide 7.0.6
Locally all works fine. That`s first time when i do things like that by myself. Have no idea what can cause this. I thought that the reason was the OS differences, but all the resources said that it should work.

Add your Jenkins pipeline script so we can better see if you are missing something. Also take a look at this answer and try checking the things listed there.
